# Некорректная работа companion object во вложенном классе

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, jetbrains

Несколько дней назад написал код, который вызвал у меня двухчасовой ступор - в `null` - безопасном Kotlin `null` появлялся там, где его никак не могло быть. В итоге источник проблемы был найден, решение однострочное. Однако. Я уверен, что текущее поведение программы некорректно.

Минимальный пример:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(Outer().outersGetProperty)
    println(Outer.outersCompanion)
    println(Outer.Inner.innersCompanion)
}

class Outer {

    val outersGetProperty: List<Inner>
        get() = Inner.innersCompanion

    companion object {
        val outersCompanion: List<Inner> = listOf(Inner.First, Inner.Second)
    }

    open class Inner {
        object First : Inner()
        object Second : Inner()

        companion object {
            val innersCompanion: List<Inner> = listOf(First, Second)
            //val innersCompanion: List<Inner> by lazy { listOf(First, Second) } //полностью рабочий вариант, который я использую сейчас
        }
    }
}
```

Вывод данного кода:

> [null, Outer$Inner$Second@179d3b25]
>
> [Outer$Inner$First@254989ff, Outer$Inner$Second@179d3b25]
>
> [null, Outer$Inner$Second@179d3b25]

В коде жестко указан тип, гарантирующий отсутствие `null`, и тем не менее `null` там есть!

Вполне возможно, моих знаний просто недостаточно, чтобы понять, что именно вызывает такое поведение, но даже если этому есть технически обоснованное объяснение и иначе сделать просто нельзя, то о таких вещах просто обязана предупреждать студия!

Прошу поделиться опытом, объяснить, чем вызвано такое поведение, может еще кто-то сталкивался.

P.s. Код изначально писался в AndroidStudio, к минимальному примеру приводился в Intellij IDEA 2020.1. Обе ide не выдали ни варнингов, ни предупреждений, хотя должны бы, потому они в тегах.

Kotlin plugin в IDEA версии 1.3.72-release-IJ2020.1-1.

Comment: Все очень похоже на косяк самого Котлина, где-то недоглядели с синглтонами для конкретного кейса. Думаю, вам сюда :) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT

Comment: А как workaround вариант с lazy вполне себе рабочий.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja уже 3 часа, как там отписался, в начале подумал, что, может быть, сам туплю, но потом понял, что это 100% баг. И да, баг для меня некритичный (за счет ленивой инициализации) - я уже дня три, как закрыл этот кейс, просто только сейчас время появилось создать минимальный пример. Изначально-то там куда больше структура классов была)